# How to apply the type to a NSFetchRequest instance?

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

In Swift 2 the following code was working:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: String)
```

but in Swift 3 it gives error:

> Generic parameter "ResultType" could not be inferred

because `NSFetchRequest` is now a generic type. In their documents they wrote this:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Animal> = Animal.fetchRequest
```

so if my result class is for example `Level` how should I request correctly?

Because this not working:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Level> = Level.fetchRequest
```

Comment: What is the description of the error?

Comment: generic parameter "ResultType" could not be inferred

Comment: link to new features, where I found the code: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/General/WhatNewCoreData2016/index.html

Comment: It's a method, so it should be `let request: NSFetchRequest<Level> = Level.fetchRequest()`

Comment: Or just `let request = Level.fetchRequest()`

Comment: @MartinR That would not pass compilation because it's ambigious.

Comment: @Sulthan: OK. (It was a guess because I don't have access to Xcode 8 at the moment :)

Comment: @MartinR seems stack overflow members love you a lot. They'll upvote you blindly. :P

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Level.fetchRequest()
```

or

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Level> = Level.fetchRequest()
```

depending which version you want.

You have to specify the generic type because otherwise the method call is ambiguous.

The first version is defined for `NSManagedObject`, the second version is generated automatically for every object using an extension, e.g:

```
extension Level {
    @nonobjc class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Level> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Level>(entityName: "Level");
    }

    @NSManaged var timeStamp: NSDate?
}
```

The whole point is to remove the usage of String constants.

Comment: So for every entity, do I need to add extension code? Or that happens automatically? So if I have a "Dog" entity and "Cat" entity, do I need "extension Dog { @nonobjc... }" and "extension Cat { @nonobjc...}"?

Comment: @DaveG That extension is generated for you automatically.

Comment: Okay, ty, but I'm a bit confused because I tried 'let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<myEntityName>(entityName: "myEntityName")' and I got the error "Use of undeclared type "myEntityName"

Comment: Note: The method fetchRequest() is only available in iOS 10

Comment: @Sulthan Hi, When I tried with your code, the following error occurs. `Type 'Project Name' does not conform to protocol 'NSFetchRequestResult'`

Comment: @DavidJonker In most situations you want the second option.

Comment: @Sulthan i tried with second option `let request: NSFetchRequest<Level> = Level.fetchRequest()` but the error occurs.

Comment: @DavidJonker Please, ask a question. I cannot help you with specific problems in comments.

Comment: @DavidJonker Did you find any solution of let request: NSFetchRequest<Level> = Level.fetchRequest() i tried out the sample but it gives me error "Use of undeclared type 'Entity Name'"

Comment: @KirtiParghi For me, at first it gave the error of "use of undeclared type". It was fixed by adding 'import CoreData' at the top and create a subclass for the entity

Comment: @dzensik is that true? I can run against iOS 9 and 8 without problem as long as it is swift 3.

Comment: I'm trying the same solution but I get error says "Use of unresolved identifier 'NSFetchRequest' in swift 4, is there any import required?

Comment: @Niloufar `CoreData` usually.

Answer (score 56):

I think i got it working by doing this:

```
let request:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Level")
```

at least it saves and loads data from DataBase.

But it feels like it is not a proper solution, but it works for now.

Comment: I like this solution better, as I used to have a single method that took the entity name as a parameter and just passed back an array of NSManagedObjects.

Comment: Liked this too because it didn't require creating a custom class. Could just use entity name!

Answer (score 33):

The simplest structure I found that works in 3.0 is as follows:

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<Country>(entityName: "Country")
```

where the data entity Type is Country.

When trying to create a Core Data BatchDeleteRequest, however, I found that this definition does not work and it seems that you'll need to go with the form:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Country.fetchRequest()
```

even though the ManagedObject and FetchRequestResult formats are supposed to be equivalent.

Comment: The first structure mentioned in this answer is the only way I can currently get this to compile with my fetched results controller on Swift3 / iOS 10 / Xcode 8.

Comment: That was my experience after trying various forms.  Did they cover any other forms in the CoreData presentation?  Plan to check it out tomorrow...

Comment: The first example is the simplest way I've found without having to use the `if #available(iOS 10.0) { ... }` conditional

Answer (score 15):

Here are some generic CoreData methods that might answer your question:

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

func addRecord<T: NSManagedObject>(_ type : T.Type) -> T
{
    let entityName = T.description()
    let context = app.managedObjectContext
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: entityName, in: context)
    let record = T(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)
    return record
}

func recordsInTable<T: NSManagedObject>(_ type : T.Type) -> Int
{
    let recs = allRecords(T.self)
    return recs.count
}


func allRecords<T: NSManagedObject>(_ type : T.Type, sort: NSSortDescriptor? = nil) -> [T]
{
    let context = app.managedObjectContext
    let request = T.fetchRequest()
    do
    {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)
        return results as! [T]
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
        return []
    }
}

func query<T: NSManagedObject>(_ type : T.Type, search: NSPredicate?, sort: NSSortDescriptor? = nil, multiSort: [NSSortDescriptor]? = nil) -> [T]
{
    let context = app.managedObjectContext
    let request = T.fetchRequest()
    if let predicate = search
    {
        request.predicate = predicate
    }
    if let sortDescriptors = multiSort
    {
        request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    }
    else if let sortDescriptor = sort
    {
        request.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    }

    do
    {
        let results = try context.fetch(request)
        return results as! [T]
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
        return []
    }
}


func deleteRecord(_ object: NSManagedObject)
{
    let context = app.managedObjectContext
    context.delete(object)
}

func deleteRecords<T: NSManagedObject>(_ type : T.Type, search: NSPredicate? = nil)
{
    let context = app.managedObjectContext

    let results = query(T.self, search: search)
    for record in results
    {
        context.delete(record)
    }
}

func saveDatabase()
{
    let context = app.managedObjectContext

    do
    {
        try context.save()
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Error saving database: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Assuming that there is a NSManagedObject setup for Contact like this:

```
class Contact: NSManagedObject
{
    @NSManaged var contactNo: Int
    @NSManaged var contactName: String
}
```

These methods can be used in the following way:

```
let name = "John Appleseed"

let newContact = addRecord(Contact.self)
newContact.contactNo = 1
newContact.contactName = name

let contacts = query(Contact.self, search: NSPredicate(format: "contactName == %@", name))
for contact in contacts
{
    print ("Contact name = \(contact.contactName), no = \(contact.contactNo)")
}

deleteRecords(Contact.self, search: NSPredicate(format: "contactName == %@", name))

recs = recordsInTable(Contact.self)
print ("Contacts table has \(recs) records")

saveDatabase()
```

Comment: Clean and elegant. Wish I could vote this up 100! One touchup, wondering what you think, I wrapped each method with context?.perform({}) for thread safety. This is recommended by Apple.

Comment: Not very OO.  Unless you were able to write these as an extension to NSManagedObjectContect, that would then be a nice solution.

Comment: Just noticed - to count all of the records you are retrieving them and then counting the number of array entries - this is really inefficient.  You probably want to expand the recordsInTable function to utilise context.count(request)

Comment: These are nice additions and should have more votes up, but probably doesn't because it's a digression away from the main question (even though it's useful). Something I would suggest hard on to change with the delete function, is to delete with the `NSManagedObjectID` instead. So before `context.delete(record)` add in  `let record = context.object(with: record.objectID)` and use that record object to delete.

Answer (score 6):

This is the simplest way to migrate to Swift 3.0, just add `<Country>`

(tested and worked)

```
let request = NSFetchRequest<Country>(entityName: "Country")
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0  This should work.

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSManagedObject.fetchRequest()
request.entity = entityDescription(context)
request.predicate = predicate
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had "ResultType" could not be inferred errors. They cleared once I rebuilt the data model setting each entity's Codegen to "Class Definition". I did a brief writeup with step by step instructions here:

[Looking for a clear tutorial on the revised NSPersistentContainer in Xcode 8 with Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39586084/looking-for-a-clear-tutorial-on-the-revised-nspersistentcontainer-in-xcode-8-wit/39652330#39652330)

By "rebuilt" I mean that I created a new model file with new entries and attributes. A little tedious, but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

What worked best for me so far was:

```
let request = Level.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Level>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved it with the following steps:

- Select your xcdatamodeld file and go to the Data Model Inspector
- Select your first Entity and go to Section class
- Make sure that Codegen "Class Definition" is selected.
- Remove all your generated Entity files. You don't need them anymore.

After doing that I had to remove/rewrite all occurences of fetchRequest as XCode seem to somehow mix up with the codegenerated version.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

func loadItemsCategory() {

    let request: NSFetchRequest<Category> = Category.fetchRequest()
    
    do {
        categoryArray = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    
    tableView.reloadData()
    
}
```