# XCode 8 CoreData auto generated Base classes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I use Xcode 8 CoreData with auto generated Base classes.

When I try
`let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Event> = Event.fetchRequest()`

fetchRequest variable correctly gets type of `NSFetchRequest<Event>`

When I try
`let fetchRequest = Event.fetchRequest()`

Xcode tells that fetchRequest has undefined type, as I understand Swift must determine type automatically by making assignment

Here is the auto generated class extension generated by Xcode

```
extension Event {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Event>        {
    return NSFetchRequest<Event>(entityName: "Event");
}

@NSManaged public var ffff: String?
@NSManaged public var timestamp: NSDate?
```

}

As an example this code works correctly (logic is the same)

```
struct MyStruct<T>  {
    let myVar: T
}

class MyClass {

}

extension MyClass {
    class func test() -> MyStruct<Int> {
        return MyStruct<Int>(myVar: 5)
    }
}

let b = MyClass.test()
```

`let b` has a correct type of `MyStruct<Int>`

Comment: Looks like a duplicate  of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810967/how-to-apply-the-type-to-a-nsfetchrequest-instance to me.

Comment: The question is why using `let fetchRequest = Event.fetchRequest()` does not determine the type of fetchRequest
but using `let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Event> = Event.fetchRequest()` works

Answer (score 0):

CoreDate automatically generated

```
@objc(Event)
public class Event: NSManagedObject {

}

extension Event {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Event> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Event>(entityName: "Event");
    }

    @NSManaged public var timestamp: NSDate?

}
```

`NSManagedObject` protocol is in Objective-C and it has class method

```
+ (NSFetchRequest*)fetchRequest
```

When i try to use `let fetchRequest = Event.fetchRequest()` it thinks that i call Objective-C `+ (NSFetchRequest*)fetchRequest` and it has no generics

Why doesn't it use an overridden `@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Event>` from an Event class extension?

Comment: This looks like you're asking your question again instead of answering it.