# swift 3 - pass entity as argument to function

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

In an earlier version of swift, I had a core data function

```
func retrieveItemsForRelatedEntity(entity: String, relatedEntity: String, identifier: String, sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?) -> Array<AnyObject>? {

    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let frequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
    frequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    if sortDescriptors != nil {
        frequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors
    } 

    switch relatedEntity {
    case "CostCentre":
        frequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "costCentre.identifier == '\(identifier)'")
        return try! context.executeFetchRequest(frequest)
    case "CostCentreDay":
        frequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "costCentreDay.identifier == '\(identifier)'")
        return try! context.executeFetchRequest(frequest)
    case "Resource":
        frequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "resource.identifier == '\(identifier)'")
        return try! context.executeFetchRequest(frequest)
    case "ResourceDay":
        frequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "resourceDay.identifier == '\(identifier)'")
        return try! context.executeFetchRequest(frequest)
    case "CostedDay":
        frequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "costedDay.identifier == '\(identifier)'")
        return try! context.executeFetchRequest(frequest)
    default:
        print("wrong entity for this function")
        return nil
    }
}
```

With Swift 3.0, the "Generic Result Type cannot be inferred", so instead of passing in the entity title Strings, can I pass in the entity Type, and switch on that for my fetch request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
let frequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity)
```

Comment: I eventually realised I didn't need to pass the entity description after all.  Unfortunately the question title may be misleading for others down the track.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question

> so instead of passing in the entity title Strings, can I pass in the entity Type, and switch on that for my fetch request?

Yes, that would be the best approach. Something like

```
 retrieveItemsForRelatedEntity(entity: NSManagedObject, relatedEntity: String, identifier: String, sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?) -> Array<AnyObject>? {
```

[From another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810967/how-to-apply-the-type-to-a-nsfetchrequest-instance)

> You have to specify the generic type because otherwise the method call is ambiguous.
>
> The first version is defined for NSManagedObject, the second version is generated automatically for every object using an extension, e.g:

This extension is automatically generated (as can be seen below with the `Animal` type.

**From Apple's Documentation on changes from `Swift 2` to `Swift 3`**

> NSFetchRequest is now a parameterized type based on a new NSFetchRequestResult protocol.

The function name for `executeFetchRequest(...)` also changed in Swift 3

```
public func fetch<T : NSFetchRequestResult>(_ request: NSFetchRequest<T>) throws -> [T]
```

Apple Documentation example of changes to `NSFetchRequest`

**Swift 2**

```
func findAnimals() {
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:”Animal")
    do {
        guard let searchResults = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as? [Animal] else {
            print("Results were not of the expected structure")
        }
        ... use(searchResults) ...
    } catch {
    print("Error ocurred during execution: \(error)")
}
```

}

**Swift 3**

```
func findAnimals() {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Animal> = Animal.fetchRequest
    do {
        let searchResults = try context.fetch(request)
        ... use(searchResults) ...
    } catch {
        print("Error with request: \(error)")
    }
}
```

So converting your code in Swift 2 for creating `NSFetchRequest`

```
let frequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entity)
```

to Swift 3

```
let frequest: NSFetchRequest<YourEntityType> = YourEntityType.fetchRequest()
```

and

```
context.executeFetchRequest(frequest)
```

will be

```
context.fetch(frequest)
```

*Note:* From other examples across the web the Apple docs code example of `Animal.fetchRequest` may be wrong and instead should be `Animal.fetchRequest()`

Answer (score 2):

please try this. It helped me.

```
func retrieveItemsForRelatedEntity(entity: String, relatedEntity: NSEntityDescription, identifier: String, sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor]?) -> Array<AnyObject>? {

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let frequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entity)
```

and

```
switch relatedEntity {
    case NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "CostCentre", in: context)!:
```