# Casting to fetchRequest in Swift 3 and Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I'm using Swift 3, Core Data, and a `NSFetchedResultsController`, and I'm forced to do the following:

```
let fetchRequest = Project.fetchRequest() as! NSFetchRequest<Project>
```

Why can't I just write `let fetchRequest = Project.fetchRequest()`? I see that `Project.fetchRequest` returns a `NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>`, but shouldn't it be able to infer `NSFetchRequest<Project>` since I'm using the `Project` entity?

Of course, I could write

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<Project>(entityName: "Project")
```

but I would like to avoid the use of strings for the entity name. Thanks for any help!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810967/how-to-apply-the-type-to-a-nsfetchrequest-instance.

Comment: I saw that post, and in both cases it forced me to cast it to `NSFetchRequest<Project>`. I find this very strange, but I guess I'll have to live with it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In `NSManagedObject` there is a method:

```
class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>
```

If you use automatic code generation for model objects, then each generated class will have a method:

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ClassName> {
   return NSFetchRequest<ClassName>(entityName: "EntityName")
}
```

For example if you have the following hierarchy of models:

```
Animal
- Cat
- Dog
```

Then XCode will generate the following methods:

```
// for Animal model object
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Animal> {
   return NSFetchRequest<Animal>(entityName: "Animal")
}

// for Cat model object
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Cat> {
   return NSFetchRequest<Cat>(entityName: "Cat")
}

// for Dog model object
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Dog> {
   return NSFetchRequest<Dog>(entityName: "Dog")
}
```

In this case, when you write `Cat.fetchRequest()` the compiler does not know which of the 3 overloads to choose.

1. This request will return all animals, cats, and dogs:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Animal> = Cat.fetchRequest()
```

2. This request will return only cats:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Cat> = Cat.fetchRequest()
```

3. And this query will return all the animals, cats and dogs, but the result will not be typed:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Cat.fetchRequest()
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: If you use standard generated classes for your Core Data entities, use this:

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<MyEntity> = MyEntity.fetchRequest()
```

You must cast the `NSFetchRequest` object to a specific entity class, otherwise Swift doesn't know the result type of the request.