# NSFetchRequest argument error

Tags: swift, nsfetchrequest

I'm getting a compiler error with the following code. `Scores` is dynamically generated data entity (Codegen - Class Defnition). The exact error is:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSFetchRequest<Scores>' to expected argument type 'NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>'

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) { 
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let request: NSFetchRequest<Scores> = Scores.fetchRequest()
    do {

        scores = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print("Error")
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The error occurs on the `context.fetch()` call. Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: Replace fetchrequest creation with below line
let request: NSFetchRequest< NSFetchRequestResult > = Scores.fetchRequest()

This has more leads on similar problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810967/how-to-apply-the-type-to-a-nsfetchrequest-instance

Comment: Ahh I actually read that and missed it. My syntax is for a custom  entity class, which is what I started with but later changed to dynamic Codegen. @pkallu suggestion and casting the result to the entity on the fetch line fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Replace fetchrequest creation with below line

`let request:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Scores.fetchRequest()`

This has more leads on similar problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37811827/6249982